# Closest non-Homebrew class to Potions Master / Salve-Maker?

Tags: dnd-5e, class, alchemist

I've been searching for a character build where it focuses on Potions crafting. To be specific, a character that would be able to craft potions as an (in-combat) action, and where the potions crafted made by me have better effects -- i.e. Healing Potions don't have to be consumed, it can be thrown towards an ally and the effects would take effect as usual (e.g. 2d4+2HP -- but maybe -1HP because of the collision with the bottle and the character).

But of course without Homebrew, that's pretty much just a preference. I've seen the [Salve Master here](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Salve-Maker_(5e_Class)).

Do you guys think there'd be something as close to what I'm trying to build? (*A merchant-like character that has a knock for concoctions and potions*) It doesn't have to be an actual separate class. I'm also open to build suggestions that stick with just the 5e PHB details.

Comment: How do you craft a potion in combat?

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker Depends I guess. I was thinking so long as the ingredients are on-hand (or in the bag) I'd be able to instantly craft a potion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Artificer: Alchemist from Unearthed Arcana...**

... is probably the closest you're going to get that resembles an "official" class of character.

You can create a handful of concoctions out of your alchemist's satchel, and you can infuse an item with a spell, allowing another character/creature to hold that item for 8 hours and use that spell.  It's not exactly what you're looking for, but I'm not aware of anything else that goes in that direction. [Here's the link](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/1_UA_Artificer_20170109.pdf) to the .pdf of that UA.

Comment: You know an UA is broken when they need to clearly state the vials "disappear" so some munchkin won't just retire and make a business out of pulling free vials out of their.... ...satchel.

Comment: Very nice. I can't believe I missed finding this. However, I was hoping I could find a certain build that sticks to the official 5e PHB. Will wait for a few more days maybe someone could suggest a build as well. Cheers! :)

Comment: My apologies, I added a response but then realised you were looking for Non-Homebrew.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the Artificer is now published (still with an Alchemist subclass) in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* and *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*.

Answer (score 8):

#### Artificer is an official class as of 2019.

With the release of *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, [Artificer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer) was canonized as a complete class available to players. In terms of mechanics and concept, it is very similar to the Unearthed Arcana artificer class from [2019](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer-2019.pdf), and less similar to the Unearthed Arcana artificer from [2017](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/1_UA_Artificer_20170109.pdf).

The [artificer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer) can produce spell effects in the form of chemicals, so an artificer's spellcasting would seem like crafting potions or acids in combat. They can also create magical inventions by infusing nonmagical items with new magical effects.

The official class also has an Alchemist subclass, which specializes in making elixirs and explosives, which function as spells and support features.

Answer (score 3):

## You want to be a re-skinned Cleric

If you just want a PHB class that can do "magic" things at a distance such as healing people, you want to be a Cleric. Oh, feel free to call it something else. Even if the book says you're casting Healing Word, you can describe and flavor it as quickly brewing a potion and throwing it to your ally. Your "holy symbol" is really "potion-making tools". Maybe "preparing spells" is actually "preparing salves" or "preparing ingredients" or the like. Basically, use all the rules of a Cleric, so you have a "standard" balanced class, but give new names to everything that fit the flavor you're looking for.

For support for the idea of reskinning things, I present a quote from Jeremy Crawford, lead designer of D&D, who had [this to say on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/930976499280232449):

> I encourage players to reskin classes/subclasses/backgrounds liberally. Take the class/subclass/background that fits the function you want for a character, and then tell your character's unique story.

That is, look for "close-enough" functionality, and use those mechanics. But your playgroup shouldn't feel constrained to the by-the-book description of those mechanics if there's another way to describe them that works better for the story you all want to tell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying the same thing myself but I wanted to try to stay away from the Alchemist Artificer because I wanted more versatility than that offered, and I felt that would be too limiting anyway.

The campaign I'm building for is starting us all off at level 3 with no multiclassing. My character is a Rogue Arcane Trickster who is pretending to be a elderly human Wizard. My plan is to be fast enough to zip around the battlefield in-combat, buffing my party, while being able to dodge any enemies who try to target the frail Wizard. Along with casting spells, I was planning on getting around the Alchemist Class by just taking Alchemy kits as my skill proficiency. Using the variant background rules you can take both Alchemy and Herbalism (for making healing potions and real-world type drugs/medicines using plants).

At first I wanted to pick High Elf for the extra cantrip, but now I'm considering Half-Elf for the skill buffs. Make sure you can boost your Medicine, Nature, and Arcana, and maybe History skills for preparing/learning potion recipes and Alchemy tricks. I boosted Stealth and Slight of Hand myself to be able to reverse-pickpocket potions to my teammates as a bonus action.

Versatility may differ depending on your DM. I cleared this character beforehand with my DM (and it was NOT easy). He said a lot of what I wanted to do was Homebrew, but I reminded him that if you take the Woodcarver's proficiency, you can whittle whatever you like out of wood. Say a Bard lost/broke his flute, BAM you have a new one. If you request a certain kind of drink from someone with Brewer's Supplies, then presumably he can whip it up in a jiffy. What's to stop an someone with an Alchemy and Herbology proficiency (basically an Apothecary) whipping up a potion whether before or during the battle?
My argument ended up being so convincing (and he likes me keeping a secret from the other players) that he is allowing me to carry around a wizard-like "spellbook" in which I can record the recipes of my experiments. The only stipulation is that I have to pass a skill check in order to concoct what I want to, and 3 skill checks to be able to write it down and make it whenever.

We haven't started this campaign yet, but going to try some different dispersal methods in-game. I would like to get to the point where I can chuck potions at my teammates (as a Rogue, Strength is my dump stat so you may want to change that for yourself), but in lieu of that, I would be fine with stealthily giving potions to my team, (ie slipping experiments into the barbarian's ale) throwing around Acid, Grease, and Alchemist's Fire, and mixing potions and salves when a Wizard would be preparing his spells. With Dart weapon proficiency, I might be able to use some long-ranged finesse-based attacks to buff my allies and debuff my enemies, kind of like Ana in Overwatch. At that point you may want to go for the Poisoner's kit instead of the other one, but you can make the argument that you can make effective poison with chemicals or plants so you might not need it at all.
Plus Alchemy is more versatile than just potions! It's magic chemistry! Tool Proficiencies are often overlooked but Alchemy could let you waterproof or fireproof clothing, make torches burn longer and brighter, make ADnD Fool's Gold and all sorts of things!

I hope this helps! Again, there is a lot here that you'll probably want to clear with your DM beforehand, but if they like the flavor then I'm sure you'll be fine.

TL;DR: Half-Elf Rogue (or any class with a speed-build and high Int/Wis) can be better than Alchemist Artificer.